# How do you dispose a reaction defined in a class constructor?

Tags: mobx

In some of my models I need to define a reaction in the constructor like this:

```
constructor() {

    //...some code

    const dispose = reaction(
        () => this.items.length,
        count => {
            this.setItemCount(count);
        }
    );

}
```

I am using a reaction rather than a computed (`@computed get itemCount()`) because loading `items` into state is an expensive (lots of data over network) operation and so I need to persist the most recent value so that it can be used throughout the app. The reaction is to update the value if the count changes when the items are loaded into state.

So, with the above in mind, I'm wondering when/how I would dispose of the reaction?  I want to avoid memory leaks.  I'm open to alternative ways of accomplishing what I need although I would prefer a reactive vs imperative approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways to go about this.

1. Dispose of reaction after it is done its job.

```
constructor() {

   const dispose = reaction(
       () => this.items.length,
       (count, reaction) => {
           this.setItemCount(count);
           if(count === 100) reaction.dispose() 
       }
   );

}
```

2. Some other action disposes it for you. Like a button click. Or another reaction. Whatever you need it to be, actually.

```
class myStore {
 disposer

 constructor() {
   this.disposer = reaction(
       () => this.items.length,
       (count) => this.setItemCount(count)
   );
 }

 myButtonClick = () => {
   this.disposer()
 }
}
```

3. Create a "deconstructor" method in your class that is meant to be called when you don't "need" this class/store anymore. You can use this method for dumping in anything that needs a cleanup before safely passing things to garbage collector.

```
class myStore {

  disposers = []

  constructor () {
    this.disposers.push(reaction(
        () => this.items.length,
        (count, reaction) => {
            this.setItemCount(count);
            if(count === 100) reaction.dispose() 
        }
    ))
  }

  deconstructor() {
        this.disposers.forEach((disposer) => disposer())
  }

}
```

You are responsible for calling this deconstructor too. Typically you will be calling it on component unmount. Hook example below:

```
function Example() {

  const [store] = useState(() => new myStore())

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => store.deconstructor()
  }, [])

  return <App/>
}
```

If store is global/context, you can call destructor in a frame component (a component that is always mounted in app's lifecycle), so it is run when user exits the app. I am not so sure, however, how needed is this step specifically for Mobx disposables, maybe someone can comment on this. Does not hurt to do it, though.

NB. Actually you should be doing number 3 at all times anyway, because it could be that due to some reasons, condition at 1. (or 2.) might not manage to trigger and you are left with unneeded reaction ticking in the background.

Comment: Number three is the complete solution I'm looking for.  It may not really matter right now since the component that kicks off the disposers lives for the life of the app. That said, you never know when something might change and that component unmounts and remounts for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an array of disposables + specific method to dispose them.
It's looking like:

```
class MyClass {
  ...
  disposables = [];
  ...
  constructor () {
    // constructor stuff

    this.disposables.push(reaction(
      () => this.items.length,
      count => {
        this.setItemCount(count);
      }
    ))
  }
  ...
  disposeAll = () => {
    this.disposables.forEach(dispose => dispose());
  }
}
```

This method is not useful if you want to dispose specific reaction. But in this case you can you map instead of an array.

Comment: When do you call disposeAll()?  I have entities that have reactions set in their constructor and I want to make sure the reactions are disposed when an entity is garbage collected.  It's possible I don't need to worry about this.  Just don't know.